# Why would my new SpeedLink USB microphone record a scratchy sound?

Tags: audio, recording, microphone

I bought a **USB SpeedLink SL-8707-SSV Pure Voice** microphone.

When I record with it (audacity / windows sound recorder) it records a terrible **scratching** noise:

[image]

I've looked for **drivers** but on the [company's website](http://www.speed-link.com/?p=3&cat=184&pid=2570&paus=1) it says:

> Microphones don't require drivers.
>   They will be configurated in the
>   settings of your sound card.

My computer:

- **P5QL PRO** Motherboard (I assume the "audio card" is on the board)
- **Windows 7**

I've experienced **no other sound problems** with the audio.

This is my **first USB microphone** (I've had always used the jack plug microphone).

**Is there something that I don't know about USB microphones or is this particular microphone just defect?**

Comment: "Microphones don't require drivers. They will be configurated in the settings of your sound card."  configurated??  engrish much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using Windows 7's "Set up a microphone" wizard? To access it, click start, type in `microphone` and click the link. It should walk you through positioning it correctly. setting the levels, etc, so that the sound comes through well. As far as I know, there isn't anything you're missing about USB microphones, although admittedly, I haven't used one before.

[image: wizard]

Comment: amazing, that fixed it: a webcam was the default microphone so I made my speedlink microphone the default, then ran it through the above test and it records well now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could just be simple background noise or interference.

The microphone itself seems to be a great product. It may be very sensitive so it can pick up slight sounds, such as your computer running. You can try turning down the input volume to see if the noise degrades. The sound card where your microphone input is located can also pick up digital noise from other hardware in the system. Other electronic devices nearby may also be interfering. I'd try turning down the input volume first to experiment.